# awk | why length wrong?

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I don't understand.. it's funny but i'm don't understand ))

See below, please

```
echo -n '\\prj\prj.prjjmbr.Interp\PRIL_35.jpg' | awk -F ';' '{a=length($1);print lenght a}'
```

Output is 35. It's right

```
echo -n '\\prj\prj.prjjmbr.Interp\PRIL_35.jpg' | wc -c
```

Output is 35. It's right too

```
echo -n '\\prj\prj.prjjmbr.Interp\Very long path with cyrillic symbols\полученные данные_по проект\отчеты\Отчет \Dinam_interp_2D_yujo-vost_ch_Urabor-Yahinskij_LU_2008 ( GNPTs_PurGeo ) \Otchet\GrafPril\PRIL_35.jpg' | awk -F ';' '{print length ($1)}'
```

Output is 202.

```
echo -n '\\prj\prj.prjjmbr.Interp\Very long path with cyrillic symbols\полученные данные_по проект\отчеты\Отчет \Dinam_interp_2D_yujo-vost_ch_Urabor-Yahinskij_LU_2008 ( GNPTs_PurGeo ) \Otchet\GrafPril\PRIL_35.jpg' | wc -c
```

Output is 237.

Why with non latin symbols i'm getting a different results? How i can fix it?

p.s. After fix, i need use substr function i.e. substr (path, 10, 8);

Comment: Why do you use `-F ';'`, seems useless to me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting different results with non latin symbols because there is a difference between the number of characters in a string and the number of bytes in a string. `wc -c` is returning the number of bytes, `awk` is returning the number of characters.

Make sure you use the right number. If you need to store the string, you need to know the number of bytes. If you need to display a string, you may be more interested in the number of characters.

From `man wc`:

> -c, --bytes
>          print the byte counts

From `man awk`:

> As of version 3.1.5, gawk is multibyte aware.  This means that
>   index(), length(), substr() and match() all work in terms of
>   characters, not bytes.

Comment: `wc -m` should produce the character count the OP is looking for.

Comment: gawk introduced `--characters-as-bytes` to treat all input data as single-byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your finding, and assumed it was locale related.
Not a fix, but a "work-around" ...

```
echo -n '\\prj\prj.prjjmbr.Interp\Very long path with cyrillic symbols\полученные данные_по проект\отчеты\Отчет \Dinam_interp_2D_yujo-vost_ch_Urabor-Yahinskij_LU_2008 ( GNPTs_PurGeo ) \Otchet\GrafPril\PRIL_35.jpg' | LANG=C awk -F ';' '{print length ($1)}'
```